# Wordpress Woocommerce Cart ERROR help pls

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, error-handling

I was playing around with Rank Math SEO and the next thing I see is that my cart is not working anymore. I don't think it's Rank Math's fault, but I got no idea what could be wrong. I already deactivated most of my plugins and it doesn't seem like the problems is there.

What I'm seeing in my cart page:

```
wp:woocommerce/cart-items-block
wp:woocommerce/cart-line-items-block
/wp:woocommerce/cart-line-items-block wp:woocommerce/cart-cross-sells-block
wp:heading {"fontSize":"large"}
You may be interested in…
/wp:heading wp:woocommerce/cart-cross-sells-products-block
/wp:woocommerce/cart-cross-sells-products-block
/wp:woocommerce/cart-cross-sells-block
/wp:woocommerce/cart-items-block wp:woocommerce/cart-totals-block
wp:woocommerce/cart-order-summary-block
wp:woocommerce/cart-order-summary-heading-block
/wp:woocommerce/cart-order-summary-heading-block wp:woocommerce/cart-order-summary-coupon-form-block
/wp:woocommerce/cart-order-summary-coupon-form-block wp:woocommerce/cart-order-summary-subtotal-block
/wp:woocommerce/cart-order-summary-subtotal-block wp:woocommerce/cart-order-summary-fee-block
/wp:woocommerce/cart-order-summary-fee-block wp:woocommerce/cart-order-summary-discount-block
/wp:woocommerce/cart-order-summary-discount-block wp:woocommerce/cart-order-summary-shipping-block
/wp:woocommerce/cart-order-summary-shipping-block wp:woocommerce/cart-order-summary-taxes-block
/wp:woocommerce/cart-order-summary-taxes-block
/wp:woocommerce/cart-order-summary-block wp:woocommerce/cart-express-payment-block
/wp:woocommerce/cart-express-payment-block wp:woocommerce/proceed-to-checkout-block
/wp:woocommerce/proceed-to-checkout-block wp:woocommerce/cart-accepted-payment-methods-block
/wp:woocommerce/cart-accepted-payment-methods-block
/wp:woocommerce/cart-totals-block
wp:heading {"textAlign":"center","className":"with-empty-cart-icon wc-block-cart__empty-cart__title"}
Your cart is currently empty!
/wp:heading wp:separator {"className":"is-style-dots"}
/wp:separator wp:heading {"textAlign":"center"}
New in store
/wp:heading wp:woocommerce/product-new {"columns":4,"rows":1}
```

/

THANKS[image]

Comment: How did you fix that? I am having the same problem

Comment: I didn’t. I just made a custom cart. You can do that with plugins like shopLentor or ShopEngine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to deactivate all the plugins except woocommerce and see whose cause the issue. But after you deactivate all the plugins and the result is still the same try to switch your theme.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. Just for reference im using the blocksy theme. Here are all of my plugins: Blocksy Companion, Child Theme Configurator, Select CookieYes | GDPR Cookie Consent, Dokan,  Elementor, Elementor Header & Footer Builder, ElementsKit Lite, Essential Addons for Elementor, Filter Everything — WooCoomerce Product & WordPress Filter, Fluent Forms, Font Awesome, LiteSpeed Cache, Rank Math SEO, ShopLentor, WooCommerce